# ubuntu doesn't recognize USB disk after upgrade to 14.04

Tags: usb, disk

Appreciate any thoughts on this.
fdisk does not see the USB drive(s). Was working until I upgraded from 13.10 ->14.04

Dmesg and lsusb show it:

```
> lsusb
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 058f:6362 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Card Reader/Writer
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 046d:c517 Logitech, Inc. LX710 Cordless Desktop Laser
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0d49:7010 Maxtor OneTouch <====================
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0bc2:2100 Seagate RSS LLC <=====================
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 03f0:7a04 Hewlett-Packard DeskJet D2460
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`dmesg` upon inserting my seagate :

```
[28126.919476] usb 1-1.4: USB disconnect, device number 7
[29098.566603] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
[29098.673124] usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=2100
[29098.673129] usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[29098.673132] usb 1-1.4: Product: FreeAgent Go
[29098.673135] usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: Seagate
[29098.673137] usb 1-1.4: SerialNumber: 2GE2G2ST
[29098.678202] usb-storage 1-1.4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[29098.678311] scsi13 : usb-storage 1-1.4:1.0
```

`lsblk` only shows internal disks:

```
/proc/scsi/usb-storage> lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0  39.2M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0  13.3G  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0 229.6G  0 part 
├─sda4   8:4    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0     8G  0 part 
├─sda6   8:6    0     8G  0 part 
├─sda7   8:7    0 115.8G  0 part /
└─sda8   8:8    0     8G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   0   2.7T  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   1.4T  0 part /win-photos
└─sdb2   8:18   0   1.4T  0 part /photos
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

I see this in `syslog`:

```
Apr 26 23:26:38 madmax kernel: [29098.673135] usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: Seagate
Apr 26 23:26:38 madmax kernel: [29098.673137] usb 1-1.4: SerialNumber: 2GE2G2ST
Apr 26 23:26:38 madmax kernel: [29098.678202] usb-storage 1-1.4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Apr 26 23:26:38 madmax kernel: [29098.678311] scsi13 : usb-storage 1-1.4:1.0
Apr 26 23:26:38 madmax mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 8: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4"
Apr 26 23:26:38 madmax mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 8 was not an MTP device <=== ???
```

For what its worth:

```
ii  libmtp-common                                         1.1.6-20-g1b9f164-1ubuntu2                          all          Media Transfer Protocol (MTP) common files
ii  libmtp-runtime                                        1.1.6-20-g1b9f164-1ubuntu2                          amd64        Media Transfer Protocol (MTP) runtime tools
ii  libmtp9:amd64                                         1.1.6-20-g1b9f164-1ubuntu2                          amd64        Media Transfer Protocol (MTP) library
ii  libnet-smtp-ssl-perl                                  1.01-3                                              all          Perl module providing SSL support to Net::SMTP
```

Comment: Its working now ! Commented out last line in /lib/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules:

# Autoprobe vendor-specific, communication and PTP devices
ENV{ID_MTP_DEVICE}!="1", ENV{MTP_NO_PROBE}!="1", ENV{COLOR_MEASUREMENT_DEVICE}!="1", ENV{libsane_matched}!="yes", ATTR{bDeviceClass}=="00|02|06|ef|ff", PROGRAM="mtp-probe /sys$env{DEVPATH} $attr{busnum} $attr{devnum}", RESULT=="1", SYMLINK+="libmtp-%k", MODE="660", GROUP="audio", ENV{ID_MTP_DEVICE}="1", ENV{ID_MEDIA_PLAYER}="1"

Working now....

Comment: Any idea why this works? I'm having the same issue with a camera. Haven't tried your fix yet to see if it makes any difference, but really curious what this line is for.